# file upload not working from Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to upload a file using modal. its working on file select and not on button click.

Below code is for button which calls my modal:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
         id="browseAndLoad" name="browseAndLoad">
     File Upload
 </button>
```

Below code is my modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="completeBrowse" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Upload File</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="completeBrowseBody">
                Choose and Upload
                <input type="file" name="datafile" class="form-control" /><br/>
                <div id="upload" style="display:none;">Uploading..</div>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                       id="uploadingFileButton" name="uploadingFileButton"
                       value="Upload"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <em> Click on <strong>Choose File/ Browse</strong> to select and upload a file </em>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is file upload part which i am trying to implement:

```
$('input[name="uploadingFileButton"]').ajaxfileupload({
            'params': '${formRoot.Number}:${headerModel.User}',
            'action': path,
    //      'orderID', '${formRoot.Number}',
            'onComplete': function(response) {
                $('#upload').hide();
                if(response.status)
                    alert("File SAVED!!");
            },
            'onStart': function() {
                $('#upload').show();
            }
        });
```

If i use the same code as below it works fine. But the problem is the moment I browse and select the file it uploads...
I am trying to browse and select the file when click "Choose File/ Browse" button and on upload button click file should be uploaded...

```
$('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
           'params': '${formRoot.Number}:${headerModel.User}',
            'action': path,
    //      'orderID', '${formRoot.Number}',
            'onComplete': function(response) {
                $('#upload').hide();
                if(response.status)
                    alert("File SAVED!!");
            },
            'onStart': function() {
                $('#upload').show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: And also the code snippet only works in Chrome and not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ajaxfileupload` accepts file type inputs

you should put your code

```
$('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
           'params': '${formRoot.Number}:${headerModel.User}',
            'action': path,
    //      'orderID', '${formRoot.Number}',
            'onComplete': function(response) {
                $('#upload').hide();
                if(response.status)
                    alert("File SAVED!!");
            },
            'onStart': function() {
                $('#upload').show();
            }
        });
```

in click handler of `uploadingFileButton` button

Comment: I have added an id to the button:                                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                        id="fileUploadButton">
                 Upload                                                                                  </button>

Comment: And on cilck of that button i have added my code...  I could see the alert but not the code getting executed after that. Neither any errors nor any showstoppers...                                            $("#fileUploadButton").click(function(){
           alert('Hello there');
            // My code snippet as you suggested....
        });